# LeanTween "from-to" value animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leantween

I am using [LeanTween](http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LeanTween.html) as the tween plugin of my Unity Application. But it's frustrating not having a "from-to" type tweening. For an example, I want

```cs
//Set initial alpha (from 1f) before animation
var tempColor = forceRing.color;
tempColor.a = 1f;
forceRing.color = tempColor;
//Tween alpha (to 0f)
LeanTween.alpha(forceRing.gameObject, 0f, 0.7f)
```

to look like this.

```
//Tween alpha from 1f to 0f;
LeanTween.alpha(forceRing.gameObject, 1f, 0f, 0.7f)
```

I couldn't find this functionality in LeanTween. What is the best way to achieve this, without writing wrappers or extensions for each tween type on my own?

Comment: I recommend using DoTween (http://dotween.demigiant.com/) it's much powerful.

Comment: I just checked it out, wow looks feature-rich, and the documentation is cleaner than LeanTween too. Definitely going to give it a try. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome my man :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LeanTween uses the [Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) pattern to configure tweens.

In your case recommend write the code like this

```
LeanTween.alpha(forceRing.gameObject, 
    to: 0f, 
    time: 0.7f
).setFrom(1.0f);
```

You can even chain more (optional) configurations (e.g. setting a delay or different ease type) that way:

```
LeanTween.alpha(forceRing.gameObject, 
    to: 0f, 
    time: 0.7f
.setFrom(1.0f).setDelay(0.5f).setEase(LeanTweenType.easeInSine);
```

Comment: mann! i had no clue there is a "setFrom()" method. Thank you so much. this will be helpful for many.

Comment: Brilliant product, but sometimes finding what you need can be a challenge...